# How to constrain the width of the browser to the width specified in a css class?

Tags: asp.net, width, html

In css I use a class named bodyClass to set the aspx page's body width:65%;

In the page I have <body class="bodyClass".....

I can see my page is sized...
But the browser still opens itself at the last width that was in use when it was closed...

I try width:650px; as well,  same result.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a new window via javascript and specify that window size, but you cannot arbitrarily change the size of a current browser window with css; only the content inside the window is in your control.